# Game in java, solution not working for n>3

Tags: java

This remote contains 12 keys with 2 nonfunctional keys. Each functional key has been given a unique label as shown above.
The Computer game for this console has N levels. There are certain moves in the game which are controlled using the remote. The keys for each moves changes with the number of levels i.e. number of keys for an operation is dependent on the game level, for example for third level, single move require three key [you have to press three keys in sequence for a move in third level]. A player can only press keys that are left, right, up or down to the current key and he is not allowed to press bottom row corner keys.

[image]

Suppose a player is at level 2. According to the rules he has to press 2 keys for a move (the number of keys is equal to the level). The possible Moves key will be ‘HH’, ‘HI’, ‘HG’, ‘HE’, ‘HJ’, ‘IF’ ,.. Etc

1. If a Move start from ‘J’, possible keys are ‘JJ’, ‘JH’ (count 2)
2. If a Move start from ‘H’, possible keys are ‘HH’, ‘HI’, ‘HG’, ‘HE’, ‘HJ’ (count 5)
3. If a Move start from ‘I’, possible keys are ‘II’, ‘IH’, ‘IF’ (count 3)

---

---

So for level 2, number of possible moves would be 36.

If a player is at level N, you have to find the total possible number of moves for that level.

**Input/Output Specifications**

*Input Specifications:*

Input is an integer N, which is level of the game

*Output Specifications:*

Output is an integer M, which is the total possible number of Moves

**Examples**

Input: 2

Output: 36

**Instructions**:

1) Do not write main function.

2) You can print and debug your code at any step of the code.

3) You need to return the required output from the given function.

4) Do not change the function and parameter names given in editor code.

5) Return type must be the same as mentioned in the problem statement.

6) When you submit your code, 10 test cases of different complexity level are executed in the background and marks are given based on number of test cases passed.

7) If you do not plan to complete the code in one sitting, then please save your work on a local machine. The code is saved only when it has been submitted using Submit button.

8 ) Only two submissions are allowed.

using System;

```
public class CandidateCode {

    public static int combinationCounts(int input1) {

        //Write code here

    }

}
```

Hmm so i came on this problem, where i got solution

```
    public static int combinationCounts(int input1)
    {
     final int TOT_KEYS=12;
     final int WORKING_KEYS=10;
     int moves=input1;
     return(TOT_KEYS*moves+moves+WORKING_KEYS);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int output = 0;
        int ip1 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
        output = combinationCounts(ip1);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(output));
    }
}
```

This code is only working for n=2 but not for more that 3,
can anyone have the best optimal solution for this.
kindly help me

Comment: Did you count what is the answer for levels 3, 4...? That could help.

Comment: yeah...for level-3 there are total 12 combinations..but this approach is not working for n=3, it simply calculate 49 combinations which is wrong

Comment: we need solution for N-Levels. "For level 3, if it starts at G, are the combinations GGG, GHI, GDA, GHE, GDE, GHJ, GDG, GHG, GHH, GDD, GGD, GGH, that is, 12 combinations  possible"

Comment: There are 12 combinations if you start from G, but this is not the answer you are looking for, right? You have to count all possible combinations. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah Egan that's  the twist i am looking for

Comment: I don't get it: why 36 and not 144?

Comment: please read carefully problem statement

Comment: I think you wont find any "simple formula" for this problem(thats because of non regular pattern). You have to take into consideration how many available neighbours does the key have. 
I would consider it as connected graph and count all possible paths from every node with N number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be solved used Graphs. You should define a *Node* class with *Neighbours* variable array inside it. Then for each key you need to define a Node instance with neighbours in it. Size of the neighbours array is the possible next moves. You need to add one to the size for the key itself.

Counting combinations mean counting paths. So N means depth here. When you see depth it means that *combinationCounts* method will be a recursive one. Try to call combinationCounts from itself with n-1 everytime till N is equal to zero.

Method should look like something like this;

```
public static int combinationCounts(int input1) {
        if(input1 == 0){
          return 0;
        }
        int totalPaths =0;
        for(Node key : keys){
            totalPaths = (key.neighbours.size() + 1) + combinationCounts(input1 -1);
        }
        return totalPaths;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    // your code goes here 
    //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    //cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int dp[10][16];
    vector<int> neighbours[10];
    neighbours[0]={0, 1, 3};
    neighbours[1]={0, 1, 2, 4};
    neighbours[2]={1, 2, 5};
    neighbours[3]={0, 3, 4, 6};
    neighbours[4]={1, 3, 4, 5, 7};
    neighbours[5]={2, 4, 5, 8};
    neighbours[6]={3, 6, 7};
    neighbours[7]={4, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    neighbours[8]={5, 7, 8};
    neighbours[9]={7, 9};
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        dp[i][1]=1;
    }
    for(int lv=2; lv<=n; lv++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            dp[i][lv]=0;
            for(int j=0; j<neighbours[i].size(); j++)
            {
                dp[i][lv]+=dp[neighbours[i][j]][lv-1];
            }
        }
    }
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        //cout<<i<<"->"<<dp[i][n]<<"\n";
        ans+=dp[i][n];
    }
    cout<<ans;
}
```

Solved it using dp. for 0 means A, 1 means B ......... , 9 means J.

Number of possible sequence starting from a given key 'i' in level 'lv'=  all possible sequence starting from all the neighbours of i in level 'lv-1'.